# How to embed the Netbeans Souce Code Editor in a Swing application?

Tags: netbeans-platform

Is there a way to embed the Netbeans source code editor in a Swing application without writing the app as a whole Netbeans Platform application?

Best regards,

David

Comment: I don't know of anybody that has done it, but I can't see any reasons why you can't do it. Your biggest problems are going to be working out what your dependencies are going to be. Maven may be quite a large help with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see:
http://www.antonioshome.net/kitchen/netbeans/nbms-standalone.php